# mongoose populate nested schema without model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to populate nested schemas without creating Model for the subschema, without any success.

I have a 'Question' Model, which created by 2 Schemas(Question, Option)

```
const Option = new mongoose.Schema({
  value: { type: String, required: true }
})

const Question = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  options: [Option]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', Question)
```

And I have a 'Review' Model

```
const Review = new mongoose.Schema({
  results: [
    {
      question: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' },
      option: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question.options' }
    }
  ],
  critical: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', Review)
```

Well, I want to create API /reviews that response array of review document, but populate the question and option.

I try this command but it isn't working.

```
Model.find({}).populate('results.option')
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

as populate can't reference the array of subdocuments, as you have separate Option schema, why not use that.

```
const Review = new mongoose.Schema({
  results: [
    {
      question: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' },
      option: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Option' }
    }
  ],
  critical: { type: Boolean, default: false }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Review', Review)
```